# Genymotion does not start (quit unexpectedly.)

Tags: genymotion

I was usually working with genymotion, but after I updated (to 2.7 version) it stopped working. It always close immediately, and the only message i get is:

> (genymotion quit unexpectedly.)
>   Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

The "detailed information" is huge and difficult to understand, but it starts from:
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x00000001039b8758 lh_new + 196

I tried:

- Reinstalling genymotion.
- Reinstalling virtualbox
- Removing /User/myuser/.Genymotion folder
- Removing the host-only adapter "vboxnet0" (and all the others adapters).

I can't find the log of the genymotion app. Also I can't find any lower version than 2.7 for downloading (for osx).

I am a little desperate, so any advice will be great.

Thanks in advance.
Guille

Comment: This is not correct stackoverflow website for this type of questions please use a proper website for this issues like http://superuser.com/

Comment: Sorry for that. I'll consider the next time

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem.  Tried rolling back to 2.6.0 and downloaded virtual devices all over again - Genymotion will start without crashing and devices eventually build but will no longer emulate react-native from the command line, which is all I use Genymotion for.  Hoping someone can chime in on this as Genymotion support have been unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I downloaded the 2.6 version from here: http://download.cnet.com/s/genymotion/

Comment: I had the same problem, downgraded to 2.6.0 and now it is working.